# jodatime truncates remaining months when interval is greater than a year

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to check if a given interval is greater than 12 months using the following code:

```
public void testMonths() throws Exception {
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm");
    DateTime from = format.parseDateTime("2010-01");
    DateTime until = format.parseDateTime("2011-06");

    int months = Months.monthsBetween(from, until).getMonths();

    assertTrue(months > 12); // months = 12 for some reason.
}
```

Whenever the given interval is more then a year it will truncate the remaining months in the last year.

Input I've tried running:

```
15 months will return 12 months.
25 months will return 24 months.
36 months will return 36 months.
37 months will return 36 months.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your text pattern. "mm" means "minutes" not "months". If you change your pattern to `"yyyy-MM"` you'll find it works fine.

As a guiding principle the *first* thing I would do in a situation like this is try to isolate this to the smallest possible problem. So take text parsing and the complexity of `DateTime` (time zones etc) out of the equation:

```
LocalDate from = new LocalDate(2010, 1, 1);
LocalDate to = new LocalDate(2011, 6, 1);
int months = Months.monthsBetween(from, to).getMonths();
```

Now you'll see it's 17. So then the next step would be to go back to your original code, and print out the values of `from` and `to`... and you'll see *something* like:

```
2010-01-01T00:01:00.000Z
2011-01-01T00:06:00.000Z
```

Basically, avoid text parsing unless that's *fundamentally* part of the problem you're trying to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for your useful help and advice, you answer solved this issue.